# How to select random files from a Coldfusion cfdirectory query?

Tags: image, random, coldfusion, filter

Just wondering, is there a way to select, say up to 5 random results from a ColdFusion *cfdirectory* query.

I can do this:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#expandpath("some/")#" filter="tag*.*" name="dir">
```

Which gives me all images

```
tag123.jpg
tag111.jgp
tag234.jpg...
```

I can output using *maxrows*, but is there a way to pick for example 5 random images out of a total filtered 20 images?

Thanks for some insights!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know there's `RandRange()` right?  Just randomly pick a row out of that query.

Add extra logic to ensure there're no repeat if you want.